# Slow and jerky Android Custom Listview

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, hashmap

I've tried all the basic things like moving every heavy task to Async task, using cached references of views in getview(), enabling scrolling/drawing cache etc so please don't suggest them. I've identified the problem to be with using the ArrayList.

I am using a ArrayList with Hashmap to hold the data.

```
static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mainList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Adapter Code :

```
public static class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.artist = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.artist);
            holder.duration = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.duration);
            holder.newsid = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.newsid);
            holder.thumb_image = (ImageView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_image);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();

        try {
            song = data.get(position);

            // Setting all values in listview

            if (song.get(MainActivity.TAG_SELECTED)
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

                final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.tick);
                chk.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.tick);
                chk.setChecked(true);
            }

            holder.newsid.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_ID));

            holder.title.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_TITLE));
            holder.title.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            holder.title.setTextSize(16);
            holder.artist.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_DESCRIPTON));
            holder.artist.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            holder.artist.setTextSize(13);
            holder.duration.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_CREATED));
            holder.duration.setTextSize(12);

            imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_IMAGE),
                    holder.thumb_image);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return vi;
    }
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: then what problem you ra egetting

Comment: can you post code of adapter?

Comment: @rajshree The listview is very slow and jerky while scrolling. not smooth.

Comment: for every view the above details are same then put in the viewHolder class so it will set once..

Comment: Are you using View holder pattern???

Comment: listView.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true); try this

Comment: total `getView()` method needed how u recycling views

Comment: @MehulJoisar Updated the question with code.

Comment: Not sure, but try moving `setTypeface()` and `setTextSize()` inside view creation `if-block` since you don't need to set it every time.

Comment: @user3285413 posted my answer change your code like that..

Comment: Andrew is right, i had the same problem and setting the typeface and the size in xml solved it.

Comment: Just for testing, try to remove or comment out the image loading and see if the listview still slow.   //imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_IMAGE),holder.thumb_image);

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks that seemed the issue. kalyan's method worked! Thanks a ton Kalyan , Ayoub !

Answer (score 3):

Here i am setting `TypeFace` and some default settings once and using them entire `listview`..

make sure create `TypeFace` once and use it every where.creating TypeFace is takes more resources and time too..

Crete `ViewHolder` inside `Adapeter` like this..

```
public static class ViewHolder {

    private TextView title;
    private TextView artist;
    private TextView duration;
    private TextView newsid;
    private ImageView thumb_image;
    private CheckBox chk;

    public ViewHolder(View vi) {
        title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
        artist = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        duration = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        newsid = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.newsid);
        thumb_image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        chk = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.tick);

        title.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        title.setTextSize(16);
        artist.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        artist.setTextSize(13);
        duration.setTextSize(12);
    }
}
```

And your `getView()` method will like this..

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(vi);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> song ;
    try {
        song = data.get(position);
        // Setting all values in listview
        if (song.get(MainActivity.TAG_SELECTED).equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
            holder.chk.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            holder.chk.setChecked(true);
        }
        holder.newsid.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_ID));
        holder.title.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_TITLE));
        holder.duration.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_CREATED));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_IMAGE),
                holder.thumb_image);
        holder.artist.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_DESCRIPTON));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return vi;
}
```

Take one Util class for loading Typeface like this..

```
public class TypeFaceUtil {

public static Typeface typeface;

public static Typeface getTypeface(Context context) {
    if (typeface == null) {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "arabic_font.otf");
    }
    return typeface;
}
}
```

And load the typeface once and use it entire your Application.

Comment: I cant vote since I have less reputation. But thanks a ton! This worked!!

Comment: But still its not perfect, though there is very good improvement from the previous version.Is there anything more I can do to improve performance?

Comment: where you are creating typeface and how??

Comment: on create -   myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "arabic_font.otf");

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime, are you working? or looking for a job ?

Comment: Ok - Do let me know if you are looking for a job change and / work for a product startup.

Comment: Regarding the code, what difference does this make? even now I am loading my typeface only once.

Comment: not only in this listview for your views outside this listview or in another Activity..and when you restart your Activity onCreate again called and Typeface again loaded but above code its not until application restart.and TypeFace loading takes nearly 2MB of Ram memory for some Typefaces..

Comment: There is still issue with the scrolling which I suspect is of Hashmap - not sure though. So unaccepted, otherwise no one will bother to look at the question with accepted answer. Dont worry I will finally accept answer :)

Comment: If I comment these, it works fine  holder.newsid.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_ID));
        holder.title.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_TITLE));
        holder.duration.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_CREATED));

Comment: That means loading data from those song object taking too much time which leads your listview to scroll slow..

Comment: So how much data you are maintaining in song object..if data is too much then load that in asynchronously..

Comment: Yeah - so whats the alternative possible to speed up?

Comment: set text textView is not a big task..i think your song object has more number of key and value pairs.so searching may taking much time.for this we can use AsynchTask and load data from the song object and set it..

Comment: I have some urgent work...will you wait for some time??

Answer (score 2):

Do not set custom type face and font size like below code

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
    ViewHolder holder;

    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.artist = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        holder.duration = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        holder.newsid = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.newsid);
        holder.thumb_image = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.list_image);

    holder.title.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        holder.title.setTextSize(16);
    holder.artist.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        holder.artist.setTextSize(13);
        holder.duration.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_CREATED));
        holder.duration.setTextSize(12);

        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();

    try {
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview

        if (song.get(MainActivity.TAG_SELECTED)
                .equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

            final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.tick);
            chk.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.tick);
            chk.setChecked(true);
        }

        holder.newsid.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_ID));
        holder.title.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_TITLE));
        holder.artist.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_DESCRIPTON));

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_IMAGE),
                holder.thumb_image);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return vi;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make few changes for improving the performance,

```
> set typeface and textsize in holder

> utilize the object song instead of creating it everytime
```

**Code :**

```
public static class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

//create an object of song
private static HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.artist = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        holder.duration = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        holder.newsid = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.newsid);
        holder.thumb_image = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.list_image);

        // set typeface and textsize
        holder.title.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        holder.title.setTextSize(16);
        holder.artist.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        holder.artist.setTextSize(13);
        holder.duration.setTextSize(12);


        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    // instead of creating object of song everytime,do it once only and then assign the data into that

    try {
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview

        if (song.get(MainActivity.TAG_SELECTED)
                .equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

            final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.tick);
            chk.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.tick);
            chk.setChecked(true);
        }

        holder.newsid.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_ID));

        holder.title.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_TITLE));
        holder.artist.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_DESCRIPTON));
        holder.duration.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_CREATED));

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_IMAGE),
                holder.thumb_image);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return vi;


   }
}
```